# Saving a JQuery DOM element as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to store a DOM element into a variable by using this code:

```
var save_status = $(this).siblings(".save-status")[0];
save_status.append("<img src="images/loading-small.gif" width=30 />");
```

I get the following error though:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Any idea why I might be getting this error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace

```
save_status.append("<img src="images/loading-small.gif" width=30 />");
```

with

```
save_status.append('<img src="images/loading-small.gif" width=30 />');
```

The problem is in your quotations.

Answer (score 10):

You're getting the error because your quotes are not escaped (or literal).

To answer your other question (per the title and example), you can save a *jQuery object*, or a *DOM element*, but they're not the same. For example:

```
var x = $(selector); // returns jQuery object
var y = $(selector)[0]; // returns DOM element

x.append('stuff'); // use jQuery functions directly
$(y).append('stuff'); // pass the DOM element to jQuery first
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several things. Try this example:

```
<style>
#mydiv{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
<script src="../assets/js/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#mydiv").click(function(){
        var save_status = $(this).siblings(".save-status").next();
        save_status.append('<img src="images/loading-small.gif" width=30 />');
        alert(save_status);
    });
});
</script>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div class="save-status"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The differences are the quotes and use ".next()"